# Computing the Expected Total Payout

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm playing a game. In the game I can roll Six(6) times. (A Roll - pick one of the 11 prizes randomly). Each roll have the possibility to give me 1 of the  11 prizes. Assuming probabilities are all equal (1/11). I can get the same prize multiple times. How can I calculate/formulate the average accumulated payout.

1) 1,500
2) 3,000
3) 4,000
4) 5,000
5) 6,000
6) 8,000
7) 15,000
8) 30,000
9) 40,000
10) 50,000
11) 70,000

---

Sample Scenario

I played the game, where I rolled Six(6) Times and I get the following total prize.

Rolls - Prize

1. - 1,500
2. - 70,000
3. - 8,000
4. - 15,000
5. - 40,000
6. - 3,000

Total : 137,500

However, the total prize will not always be like this. I want to compute 
, with given the probabilities, the average accumulated payout (Im not sure if its the correct term of it).

Compute the Probabilities of getting the Maximum (6 x 70,000 = 420,000) and Minimum (6 x 1,500 = 9,000) payouts and probabilities of getting whatever in between the maximum and minimum values. (if its possible to compute)

Comment: Can you get the same price twice? Could I get $\$1500$ for my first and second roll?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Yes I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $x_{i}$ is the prize you get for each experiment, you want to calculate the average of accumulated payouts, which is the same as expected value of accumulated payouts:
$$E(\sum{x_{i}})$$

Since we have $E(x_{i})=\frac{1}{11}(a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{11}) = 21,136.36$

Because
$$E(\sum{x_{i}})=\sum E(x_{i}) $$

We have
$$E(\sum{x_{i}})=\sum E(x_{i}) = 6 \times21,136.36 = 126,818$$

Comment: What if the last 4 payouts are a bit lower probability of winning? (Cant give exact values since Im still investigating the game) How would it affect the formula and result?

Comment: $E(x_{i})will decrease and the final result will decrease as well$

Comment: @Hexxed $E(xi)$ will decrease and the final result will decrease as well

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Expected Value](http://www.statisticshowto.com/expected-value/) (this page has a pretty good explanation), which is defined as $\sum_XX*P(X)$, where $X$ is the amount you get and $P(X)$ is the probability of getting that amount.

Here's a simple example. You have a $1\%$ chance of winning $\$1000$, a $1\%$ chance of winning $\$100$, and a $98\%$ chance of winning nothing. The expected value of this is $\frac1{100}*1000+\frac1{100}*100+\frac{98}{100}*0=11$ dollars.

Since you have an equal probability of getting any prize, the actual result is just the average of all the prizes times six. The expected value only finds the average amount you get per trial. If you go through six trials, you will get six times the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, suppose you roll $n$ times; and that there are $k$ equi-probable outcomes, with corresponding rewards $r_i$. Let $R(n)$ be the expected reward from $n$ rolls.

For any *single* roll, it should be clear that the expected reward is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{r_i}{k} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i$$

Since the rolls are independent, that implies that for $n$ rolls, the expected reward is

$$R(n) = \frac{n}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i$$

which, in your case is

$$\frac{6}{11}232500 \approx 126818.182$$